# SweetAlert missing ) after argument list in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sweetalert, sweetalert2

When I run below code on firefox, it runs fine but in chrome it shows error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Here is my code

```
 (data) ? (swal("Done","Your entry is saved successfully","success")
.then(value => {
  location.reload();
})) : swal("Error","Cannot reach the database. Please try again","Error");
```

I don't know how to fix this

Comment: Try removing parenthesis around first swal - 
`(data) ? swal("Done","Your entry is saved successfully","success")
.then(value => {
  location.reload();
}) : swal("Error","Cannot reach the database. Please try again","Error");`

Comment: I did that. It doesn't have any effect

Comment: Which exact location does the error show refer to?

Comment: I tried replicating the problem in Chrome but it is working as expected. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/myoh5tca/7/). Seems like your problem is caused by other parts of your code.

Comment: Make sure all your browser extensions are disabled.

Comment: After I completely uninstalled and installed chrome again, it magically worked